# how to get gray values for a set of x and y coordinates in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, coordinates, grayscale

With this code:

```
gray = rgb2gray(I5);
imtool(gray)
graydata = 0;
graydata = gray(sub2ind(size(gray)),(y(:)),(x(:)));
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in fourierdescriptorscode (line 18)
```

This is line 18:

```
graydata = gray(sub2ind(size(gray)),(y(:)),(x(:)));
```

Comment: Can you give as a few more details? What error did occur?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

to get values for a specific x and y coordinate, simply provide them as indicies. For example you want pixel row 2, column 3

```
pixel_of_interest = gray(2,3);
```

if you have an index and want to get the corresponding row column val

```
[row_of_interest, col_of_interest] = ind2sub(size(gray),INDEX_OF_INTEREST);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a misplaced parenthesis. `sub2ind` takes a minimum of 3 parameters:

```
graydata = gray(sub2ind(size(gray)),(y(:)),(x(:)));
                        move this ^             ^ after this...
graydata = gray(sub2ind(size(gray),(y(:)),(x(:))));
```